# Getting names from HTML file via python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_players(team_id, year):
    """
    Get a list of players in a team in a given year.
    Inputs:
        team_id: string, a three-letter id of the team
        year: integer, a year
    Returns:
        a list of strings that are the players' names
    """
    link = "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/{}/year/{}/".format(team_id, year)
    soup = soup_link(link)

    game_stat_row = soup.find("tr", {"class": "colhead"})

    player_names = []
    for name in game_stat_row:
        player_names.append(name)

    return player_names
```

Hi I want to get player names from this URL: http://espn.go.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/por/year/2015/ but it always giving some html text but not the list of players. I need to find first occurence of each name and get it once. Can you help me. Thanks. I am using BeautifulSoup for this by the way.

Comment: `"colhead"` is the wrong classname...

Comment: be careful with your quest.  Scraping that website of data is most likely going to get your IP address banned

Comment: @Jeff only if he accesses it too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a different way to get the html code here

```
source = urllib2.urlopen(link)
html = source.read()
source.close();
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

since i noticed that all rows end with a number so i used regex to extract those rows

```
players_table = soup.find_all("tr",{"class" : re.compile(r"\d+$")})
```

here is all the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
import re

def get_players(team_id, year):
    link = "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/{}/year/{}/".format(team_id, year)
    source = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    html = source.read()
    source.close();
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


    players_table = soup.find_all("tr",{"class" : re.compile(r"\d+$")})
    player_names = []
    for table in players_table:
        for a in table.find_all('a'):
            player_names.append(a.get_text())

    return player_names
```

Comment: Your contribution would have more value to the site if you included some explanation with it describing what problem in the original post it addresses and how.

Answer (score 0):

This part is causing issues:

```
game_stat_row = soup.find("tr", {"class": "colhead"})

player_names = []
for name in game_stat_row:
    player_names.append(name)
```

Instead, assuming this is an [example roster](http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/bos/year/2014), you need to find all player names from the `my-teams-table` table. Working sample:

```
player_names = [player.get_text() for player in soup.select("#my-teams-table a[href*=player]")]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> content = requests.get("http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/bos/year/2014").content
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> [player.get_text() for player in soup.select("#my-teams-table a[href*=player]")]
['Avery Bradley', 'Jae Crowder', 'R.J. Hunter', 'Jonas Jerebko', 'Amir Johnson', 'David Lee', 'Jordan Mickey', 'Kelly Olynyk', 'Terry Rozier', 'Marcus Smart', 'Jared Sullinger', 'Isaiah Thomas', 'Evan Turner', 'James Young', 'Tyler Zeller']
```

Comment: It gives me error that Beautiful Soup is not HTTP client. Anyway i need to get names under Player head in first table which class "colhead" there i am stuck. Sorry

Comment: @user5372470 I don't know what else to provide. There is a working code in the answer that does exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: `def get_players(team_id, year):

    content = requests.get("http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/{}/year/{}/").format(team_id, year)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    player_names = [player.get_text() for player in soup.select("#my-teams-table a[href*=player]")]
    return player_names`

Comment: I need to use inside above function because i will add more things to it that is why. Thanks

Comment: @user5372470 you are not defining the content correctly. Should be `content = requests.get("http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/{}/year/{}/".format(tea‌​m_id, year)).content`